# Materialize nested accordian

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I am having issues with a nested accordian - whenever I click the child element, the parent accordian closes ....

I'm using this HTML :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header">
            <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 m12">
                    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
                        <li>
                            <div class="collapsible-header">
                                <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Nested First</div>
                            <div class="collapsible-body">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="collapsible-header">
                                <i class="material-icons">place</i>Nested Second</div>
                            <div class="collapsible-body">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="collapsible-header">
                                <i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Nested Third</div>
                            <div class="collapsible-body">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header">
            <i class="material-icons">place</i>Second</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header">
                            <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Nested First</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header">
                            <i class="material-icons">place</i>Nested Second</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header">
                            <i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Nested Third</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header">
            <i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12 m12">
                        <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
                            <li>
                                <div class="collapsible-header">
                                    <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Nested First</div>
                                <div class="collapsible-body">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="collapsible-header">
                                    <i class="material-icons">place</i>Nested Second</div>
                                <div class="collapsible-body">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="collapsible-header">
                                    <i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Nested Third</div>
                                <div class="collapsible-body">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header">
            <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Fourth</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
            <div style="padding:25px">
                <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header">
                            <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Nested First</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header">
                            <i class="material-icons">place</i>Nested Second</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="collapsible-header">
                            <i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Nested Third</div>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I can't figure out what is causing it to happen...

When I initialise the accordian using: 
`$('.collapsible').collapsible();`
I set the `onOpen` and `onClose` callbacks to alert "open" or "closed".

When clicking on a child element it seems to alert open, but then alerts close so it's triggering the child but immediately closing the whole accordion.

Any help or tips would be much aprpeciated

Comment: Your sample code appears to be working, unless I'm mis-understanding your issue

Comment: This is what I mean, it is working in a codepen but putting it into my application it doesn't work, must be something javascript based or the fact it is wrapped in a container ....

Answer (score 0):

Just change the nested collapsible to id and have another function to call ("#newid").collapsible()

Comment: what i mean is add an id attribute along with class attribute

Comment: Please, describe this in the answer itself, not adding a comment below it.